# Simpledateformat is not parsing milliseconds

Tags: java, simpledateformat

```
String dateTimePattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS";
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(dateTimePattern);
Date startTime = sdf.parse("2014-03-14 04:16:58.666");
System.out.println(startTime);
```

Output

```
Fri Mar 14 04:16:58 CDT 2014
```

Why is not printing milliseconds?

Comment: This is because you are printing using the default `Date`'s `.toString()` implementation; if you want another format, reuse your `SimpleDateFormat` which has a method to format a `Date` into a `String`

Comment: Date is a container of milliseconds since the Unix epoch, it has no concept of format (beyond what the current local provides), you can not change this, this is the job of a DateFormatter. Comtinuation to try and change the for at of Date will sinks continue to frustrate you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is not that the milliseconds are not getting parsed, your `startTime` includes the milliseconds you have provided. The problem is that they are not getting printed.

You need to format your output if you want something other than the default format from [`Date#toString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#toString%28%29):

> *Converts this Date object to a String of the form:
>    dow mon dd hh:mm:ss zzz yyyy*

You can use your `SimpleDateFormat` to format your output too, which will give you milliseconds:

```
System.out.println(sdf.format(startTime));
```

Comment: You already have that in `startTime`, this just affects the output.

Comment: you are right! even if sdf.parse does not print output in milliseconds while returning data to database ,it shows milliseconds there.

Answer (score 3):

You are printing `startTime` directly (e.g. the toString() from java.util.Date); if you want your output to match your specified DateFormat you could do -

```
 String dateTimePattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS";
 SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(dateTimePattern);
 Date startTime = sdf.parse("2014-03-14 04:16:58.666");
 System.out.println(sdf.format(startTime)); // <-- use the DateFormat.
```

Which will output

```
2014-03-14 04:16:58.666
```

Comment: even if sdf.parse does not print output in milliseconds while returning data to database ,it shows milliseconds there.

Answer (score 1):

The other answers are correct.

## Avoid j.u.Date

You would have simpler code and none of that confusion if you used [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) (or [java.time package](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) in Java 8) rather than the notoriously troublesome java.util.Date & .Calendar & java.text.SimpleDateFormat classes bundled with Java.

## Joda-Time

Joda-Time has built-in automatic parsers for [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats. Your format would work if you replaced that space with a `T`.

Example code using Joda-Time 2.3…

```
String inputRaw = ( "2014-03-14 04:16:58.666" );
String input = inputRaw.replace( " ", "T" );

DateTimeZone timeZone = DateTimeZone.forID( "Europe/Paris" );
DateTime dateTime = new DateTime( input, timeZone );

DateTime dateTimeUtc = dateTime.withZone( DateTimeZone.UTC );
```

Dump to console…

```
System.out.println( "input: " + input );
System.out.println( "dateTime: " + dateTime );
System.out.println( "dateTimeUtc: " + dateTimeUtc );
```

When run…

```
input: 2014-03-14T04:16:58.666
dateTime: 2014-03-14T04:16:58.666+01:00
dateTimeUtc: 2014-03-14T03:16:58.666Z
```